# Java Enum Causing NullPointerException

Tags: java, enums, nullpointerexception

I have an enum and I am trying to iterate through it using a foreach and for some reason it is returning null on my first constant. I see nothing wrong with it.

First off, I am creating and initializing a hashmap to store the enums so that I can manipulate them to my heart's content.

```
public class ScriptLoader {
    private ResourceLocation resloc;
    private File file;
    private FileReader fr;
    private BufferedReader br;
    //Here
    private Map<String, Node> nodes;
```

Init here:

```
 public void loadScript() throws IOException{
        file = resloc.getFile();
        fr = new FileReader(file);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        //Here
        nodes = new HashMap<>();
        this.setNodes();
        if(Engine.stateOfEngine == EnumEngineState.DEBUGGER_ON) {
            Engine.LOGGER.log("\tScript Loaded!", EnumLoggerTypes.DEBUG);
        }
    }
```

Secondly, I am creating a method called `setNodes()` which will add the constants to the map in the parent class of `setNodes()` which is called `ScriptLoader`.

```
public void setNodes(){
        for(EnumNodes node : EnumNodes.values()) {
            nodes.put(node.getName(), node.getNode());
        }
    }
```

And I am calling it here:

```
public void loadScript() throws IOException{
        file = resloc.getFile();
        fr = new FileReader(file);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        nodes = new HashMap<>();
        this.setNodes();
        if(Engine.stateOfEngine == EnumEngineState.DEBUGGER_ON) {
            Engine.LOGGER.log("\tScript Loaded!", EnumLoggerTypes.DEBUG);
        }
    }
```

Now, I have an [enum](https://github.com/AlexCouch/text-game-engine/blob/master/src/org/ggg/engine/consts/EnumNodes.java) that I have a list of "nodes" that I want to iterate through, which can be seen in the `setNodes()` method.

Now the crash report is [here](https://pastebin.com/Y83czLPX). For some reason, it is pointing the `ExceptionInInitializationError` at the first enum constant, and the null pointer exception at the enum declaration. I didn't think that an enum declaration could return null.

Comment: first your pastebin is not working... Second, can you show your Enum declaration too?

Comment: post you enum code here

Comment: I did, I am saving space by using a link, and oh whoops, didn't see the pastebin not work. Lemme try that again.
EDIT: I got it to work.

Comment: The 'crash report', by which I assume you mean the stack trace, should be *here*, in your question, not at some external link.

Comment: Can you post the code for your EnumEngineState Enum too.

Comment: Re: `this.setNodes();`, prepending `this.` to a method call has no effect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From that error message, I'm guessing that something in your enum constructor is throwing an exception. Digging through your github a bit, I believe that the problem is in [Node](https://github.com/AlexCouch/text-game-engine/blob/master/src/org/ggg/engine/io/script/node/Node.java). It looks like the enums may be initialized by Java's classloader before `start` is called on an instance of [Engine](https://github.com/AlexCouch/text-game-engine/blob/master/src/org/ggg/engine/Engine.java), causing `Engine.getScriptLoader()` to return null, and `Node`'s constructor to throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: No more crash! Figured out that [this](https://github.com/AlexCouch/text-game-engine/blob/master/src/org/ggg/engine/io/script/node/Node.java#L22) should not be there. Thanks for the suggestion! You were right, it **was** in my Node class!